# Wildcard query expansion resulted in too many terms

Tags: oracle10g, wildcard, contains

I am receiving a "wildcard query expansion resulted in too many terms" error when executing a query similar to the following:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_a
 WHERE contains(clob_field, '%a%') > 0;
```

Does anyone know a workaround/solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/100465/43710/), you may need to increase the wildcard_maxterms parameter, or take further steps. See the link for details (I'm not an expert in Oracle Text though).