# oracle - catsearch string containing dash (-)

Tags: oracle, oracle-text

I have a table which has data like -

```
Table
abc-123
abc-124
abc-125
```

when I am doing below catsearch it is running fine -

```
select * from table
where  CATSEARCH (columna,'abc-*',NULL)>0
```

but when I add 1 before the *, it is giving me error

```
select * from table
where  CATSEARCH (columna,'abc-1*',NULL)>0
```

> ORA-29902: error in executing ODCIIndexStart() routine ORA-20000:
>   Oracle Text error: DRG-51030: wildcard query expansion resulted in too
>   many terms

What I am doing wrong, please help to understand the issue

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554054/wildcard-query-expansion-resulted-in-too-many-terms)  and [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46913/fixing-wildcard-expansion-resulting-in-too-many-terms-error-drg-51030)

Comment: what if you do `select * from table where Upper(columna) like 'abc-1%'`  ...?

Comment: yes upper(columna) would work but I want to use catsearch as it is faster than like

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle Text you can define some preferences while creating the index. In your case you should consider to define your own `LEXER` and printjoins.

```
BEGIN
   ctx_ddl.create_preference('INV_DEV_LEXER','BASIC_LEXER'); 
   ctx_ddl.set_attribute('INV_DEV_LEXER', 'printjoins','.-_%:;/,()?!*+@'); 
END;


CREATE TABLE inv_dev (name VARCHAR2(255));

INSERT INTO inv_dev VALUES ('abc-123');

INSERT INTO inv_dev VALUES ('abc-124');

INSERT INTO inv_dev VALUES ('abc-125');

CREATE INDEX inv_dev_idx ON inv_dev(name) 
        INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CTXCAT 
        PARAMETERS ( 
            'LEXER INV_DEV_LEXER STOPLIST CTXSYS.EMPTY_STOPLIST' 
        );

SELECT * 
    FROM inv_dev
WHERE CATSEARCH (name,'abc-1*',NULL)>0;
```

If `-` sign is not defined in printjoins and defined in skipjoins, the phrase `'abc-123'` is indexed as `'abc123'`.

Also just escaping the `-` with `\`, so:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM inv_dev
WHERE CATSEARCH (name,'abc\-1*',NULL)>0;
```